# C# trouble using delegates for cross threading

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a problem using delegates to change a `Textbox` from a thread that isn't the main form thread.

I have two class, a main Form1.cs class with the UI and another class, LINClass.cs where I wrote a device functions.
In the Form1 I start a backgroundworker that poll the device continuously, and another thread that retrieve data from the device (RXTask()), all the functions of the two threads are from LINCLass.cs.

The thread that retrieve data from the device contains a delegate that point to a Form1.cs function that permit to change the Form1 textboxes:

```
public class LINClass : Form
{
    private delegate void FormUpdater(int devnum, string rpm, string current, string temp);

//some other variables and procedure

public void RXTask()
{
    FormUpdater frmUpdt = new FormUpdater(Form1.GUIupdate);
    //other procedures and a loop containing the invoke...
    this.Invoke(frmUpdt, new object[]{devnum, rpm,
                                        current,
                                        temperature});

}
```

The Form1 class contain the method invoked, written as below

```
public static void GUIupdate(int eWPnum, string rpm, string current, string temp)
{
    //take the parameters and write them in the textbox
}
```

Now when I run the code, threads are running but I have an exception when invoke the function.

http://s13.postimg.org/9ohuj9d7r/exception.png

It says, "InvalidOperationException was not managed, Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created"

Comment: This is a well known problem. You need to google BeginInvoke for the canonical solution. Basically, you have to check for whether an invoke is required, and if it is you invoke it with the same parameters and stop executing on the wrong thread.

Comment: You are probably invoking the method before the form's `Initialize()` method has finished running. If the textboxes haven't been added to the from's control collection you will get this error.

Comment: Windows is not a real-time operating system; are you sure you want to try to poll the device **continuously**?  Are you willing to heat up an entire CPU to do nothing but that?  The battery life on my laptop will not thank you.  Why not do everything on one thread and handle the device asynchronously, rather than concurrently?

Comment: thank you all for your suggestion, at this moment I solved with a "brute force" this.CreateHandle() before the code that do the Invoke and this.DestroyHandle() after this code so every cycle the handle of the GUI is created and removed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a command pattern and put the command classes into a queue from one thread, and let the other thread read from it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I'm pretty new at object oriented code but I will study your suggestion!

Comment: you create a base class and a lot of child classes that override an execute method.each child class has a different execute method. when you want a method to be executed, you create a specific object and put it into the queue. another thread reads the queue, element by element and runs the execute method

Comment: I have a doubt so I'd like to ask you another question: I started a thread with a method that is inside the instance LIN of the class named LINClass (RXThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(LIN.RXTask));), RXThread can access all the members of the instance? or in other words, RXThread is working on the instance LIN?

Comment: should be able, if I understood you correctly. You should always be careful of threadlock and you should dedicate a couple of days to study this.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to prevent `this.Invoke()` from being called unless the form's window has been created.

The easiest way to do this is to override `OnLoad()` and set a flag:

```
private bool isLoaded;

protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    Volatile.Write(ref isLoaded, true);
}
```

Then check the flag before you invoke:

```
public void RXTask()
{
    FormUpdater frmUpdt = new FormUpdater(Form1.GUIupdate);
    //other procedures and a loop containing the invoke...

    if (Volatile.Read(ref isLoaded))
    {
        this.Invoke(frmUpdt, new object[]
        {
            devnum, rpm,
            current,
            temperature
        });
    }
}
```

(If your version of .Net doesn't have Volatile.Read()/Volatile.Write(), declare the flag as `volatile` instead.)

Comment: It is pretty iffy advice, OnHandleCreated() can run more than once.  The OP is apt to start the thread when he follows your advice and that would be very bad.  Do recommend the Load event instead.

Comment: @HansPassant I was not aware that OnHandleCreated() can be called more than once. Where is this documented? I can't find it mentioned anywhere (e.g. in [documentation like this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86faxx0d.aspx)).

Comment: Just try it yourself, change the ShowInTaskbar property for example.  I've documented this in many posts :)

Comment: @HansPassant Hmm, well Microsoft seem to have [piled quite a lot of code into `Control.OnHandleCreated()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,8da10a0bea4744f5)...

Comment: @MatthewWatson The general answer is: the function is called a extra time any time [`Control.RecreateHandle()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.recreatehandle(v=vs.110).aspx) is called. One situation of that is on [changing `ShowInTaskbar`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Windows.Forms/R/9c0f2d7c47a3ead7.html)

Comment: Wrong method, look at Control.RecreateHandle().  99 cross links, it is popular.  Just ask a question about it if you want to learn why it is necessary.

Comment: @HansPassant This is interesting: It would appear to mean that there is a race condition any time you use `Control.Invoke()` or `Control.BeginInvoke()`, since they may use a stale Handle!

Comment: No, it only uses the Handle property to determine what thread owns the object.  Underlying winapi call is GetWindowThreadProcessId().  A different handle still is going to yield the same thread.  Also the reason that it does not matter what control's BeginInvoke method you use.